# Laravel 5 Mime validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ok, I'm trying to upload a video, and validate the file type.

According to the documentation:

> **mimes:foo,bar,...**
>
> The file under validation must have a MIME type corresponding to one of the listed extensions.
>
> **Basic Usage Of MIME Rule**
>
> 'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'

I'm uploading a wmv video, and my rules are so:

```
return [
    'file' => ['required', 'mimes:video/x-ms-wmv']
]
```

I've done a `print_r()` on `Request::file('file')` and I get the following data:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
(
    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => SampleVideo.wmv
    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => video/x-ms-wmv
    [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 70982901
    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6428.tmp
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php6428.tmp
)
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
{"file":["The file must be a file of type: video\/x-ms-wmv."]}
```

I've tried changing the "mime type" to `video/*`, `wmv` (as per the docs) and also `video/x-ms-wmv` yet none of them validate the file correctly.

As you can see from the `print_r()` the mime type Symfony is getting **is** `video/x-ms-wmv`.

Am I doing something wrong? Or can Laravel/Symfony just not validate files well?

I appreciate the help

**Edit**
Ok, I opened `validator.php` and added `echo $value->guessExtension();` to the `ValidateMimes()` method, and it outputs asf.

Why is Symfony outputting `video\x-ms-wmv`, the file extension is wmv, I'm validating both of them, but Laravel is guessing `asf`?!

It's too unreliable for video validation for me.

Comment: I also had this issue and the problem was with the PHP version I was using, try creating a vanilla php file and check the mime type of a video with the Fileinfo function http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

[Laravel is](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/aa5cb848670a5aa9bd35e151eb566e359221da5a/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1244) calling [`guessExtension`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_guessExtension) on Symphony's UploadedFile object, which will return the expected **extension** of the file, not the mimetype.

This is why the documenatation states that for an uploaded image you should use:

> 'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'

Symfony's `guessExtension` calls `getMimeType`, which uses PHP's [Fileinfo Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) to go and guess the mimetype of a given file.

Once `getMimeType` guesses the mimetype for the file, Symfony's [MimeTypeExtensionGuesser](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d94d837e9ea75d76eeb0a43e0535a5e7a7a01542/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php) kicks in to get the extension from the mime type retrieved from a file.

```php
    // ... cut from MimeTypeExtensionGuesser
    'video/x-ms-asf' => 'asf',
    'video/x-ms-wmv' => 'wmv',
    'video/x-ms-wmx' => 'wmx',
    'video/x-ms-wvx' => 'wvx',
    'video/x-msvideo' => 'avi',
```

Therefore, your rules should be:

```php
return [
    'file' => ['required', 'mimes:wmv,asf']
]
```

The reason that `asf` should be included is mainly historical. To quote Wikipedia:

> The most common media contained within an ASF file are Windows Media Audio (WMA) and Windows Media Video (WMV). The most common file extensions for ASF files are extension .WMA (audio-only files using Windows Media Audio, with MIME-type '`audio/x-ms-wma`') and .WMV (files containing video, using the Windows Media Audio and Video codecs, with MIME-type '`video/x-ms-asf`'). These files are identical to the old .ASF files but for their extension and MIME-type.

*Microsoft's documentation* about [the difference between ASF and WMV/WMA files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/284094) states:

> The only difference between ASF files and WMV or WMA files are the file extensions and the MIME types [...] The basic internal structure of the files is identical.

Because the internal structure of the file is identical (including the *[magic numbers](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000067.shtml)* for the file format), wmv, wma and asf are one and the same. The only difference between the three extensions is the icon that is shown inside Explorer.

It's not just Windows Media files that will have this issue, [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) many different video container formats that will have the same problem. If you want to find the **video codec** that is being used in a container, you are going to need to look at more then just the ["*magic patterns*"](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) that are used by the `fileinfo` functions.

---

That being said, *expected behaviour* != *correct behaviour*.

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9203) to add a new validator, called `mimetypes`. This does as you would expect and uses the guessed mimetype to validate an uploaded file, instead of the extension that is guessed from the mimetype.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you know whether I was just unlucky to pick a "difficult" file type (wmv/asf) or whether this occurs with alot of other file types (that is, I expect it to be mp4, but it 'guesses' another extension, for example)?

Comment: @PhilCross, it's mainly just WMV/ASF that has this problem. mp4 has gone through a much better standardisation process :) (although, you still might have the issue where .mpv files get marked as mp4 etc, but that is to be expected - ie, you want `jpeg` files to be marked as `jpg`, etc). The problem with `wmv` is it's a container format, like `mkv`, so just because it's got ".wmv" at the end, doesn't mean that it is acutally using the `Windows Media Video` format.

Comment: Thank you for another explanation! I'll +1 the answer :)

Comment: How about Fonts in Laravel? I use Request Validation for the font but it doesn't work!
`'fontwoff2colum' => 'mimes:woff2'`

Comment: @FaridVatani the mimetype _should_ be `application/font-woff`. See https://github.com/symfony/mime/blob/master/MimeTypes.php

Comment: @TimGroeneveld I check out your Link and use fonts mimetypes in my form request validation but woff & woff2 have error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750131/laravel-font-extensions-validations