# Laravel Mime Type Validation (KML file)

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, mime-types

I have an file upload on my form with a validation rule to check that it's a kml file:

```
return [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:kml',
        ...
    ];
```

However, when I upload a .kml file I get an 'The file must be a file of type: kml.' error.

Other than the file extension where else is the mime type being defined?

Comment: You may find this usefule - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-mimes-validator-always-returning-errors-even-with-right-mime-type    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842625/laravel-5-mime-validation

Answer (score -2):

you have to specific correct kml mime which is `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`

Read more @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-mimes

Also, this page gives you full mimes https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types