# laravel 5.1 validation mimes error doesn`t display

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

hi I have this validation

```
 $this->validate($request, [
     'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png',
 ]);
```

error for required its Ok . but when your image extension in not jpeg,bmp,png i haven`t error

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842625/laravel-5-mime-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display validation errors you have to write this code in the view.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```