# Laravel 5 upload script files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a PHP script via upload form but Laravel 5 Validator rejects it.

Here's an example:

```
$input_name = 'myfile';
$requirements = 'mimes:text/x-php|required|max:10000';
$file = array($input_name => Input::file($input_name));
$rules = array($input_name => $requirements);
$validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) { // The fail occurs here
    echo Input::file($input_name)->getMimeType(); // the output is text/x-php
}
```

Debug data:

- I've also made attempts to define the mime type as `x-php` and `php`.
- At the terminal `file --mime-type test.php` returns text/x-php
- Laravel `getMimeType()` function also returns text/x-php
- The test.php file is small enough so It's not the size limit.
- The same code works for images if defined as `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required|max:10000`

Does anyone know how the script files of any type should be defined in the validator?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It came out that the Validator works with a list of mime types and extensions defined in:

`/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php`

So the unknown mime types should be defined here to be usable.

There's some more useful information here:
[Laravel 5 Mime validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842625/laravel-5-mime-validation)