# Mime type validation not working in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to validate a .pfx file but it fails all the time.

I tried the following code:

```
  $validacoes =  [
        'certificado' => 'mimetypes:application/x-pkcs12'
    ];
```

but it doesn't work.

if I do

```
dd($request->file('certificado')->getMimeType())
```

I get: application/x-pkcs12.

what can be wrong?

For images it does work: image/jpg, image/png, etc.

Comment: what do you get if you try with file extension?? `mimes:pfx`

Comment: I am almost giving up. It doesn't work for certain files, aparently.

Comment: can you test with a different file of the same type?? check if there is any other error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it should be according to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimes):

```
'certificado' => 'mimes:p12,pfx'
```

Comment: Could you share your file maybe so that we could test?

Comment: The file is a digital certificate that doesn't belong to me, so I cannot share it.

Comment: maybe you can create a blank new one that's not used anywhere? Test on it, if it still fails, share it with us? Otherwise there's not much we can do to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$validacoes =  [
        'certificado' => 'mimes:application/x-pkcs12'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.

My file:

```
"certificateFile" => UploadedFile {#5824
    -test: false
    -originalName: "file.pfx"
    -mimeType: "application/x-pkcs12"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
```

My validation rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'certificateFile' => 'required|mimetypes:application/x-pkcs12',
            'certificatePassword' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Any ideas guys?

Edit: Ok, found an answer in another question ([Laravel 5 Mime validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842625/laravel-5-mime-validation?rq=1)) that might answer our problem.

In this comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023227/2796516) it is explained that Laravel uses the [guessExtension](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_guessExtension) to validate our file. And checking the source code of said extension we find:

```
'application/x-pkcs12' => 'p12',
```

Which probably means that it only accepts certificate files with the p12 extension, pfx wont work.